# unique value angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, forms, angular4-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have an issue with Angular 4 reactive forms.

My application is a training project. It has a Backend in SpringBoot, mySql database, and forms in Angular4.

This app have to Add doctors  to Database, but also have to validate: the license number has to be uniqe. I am using Reactive Forms (not template driven).

I tried to solve my problem with function:

```
    import { AbstractControl } from "@angular/forms";



export function  ControlLicenseNumber(c: AbstractControl):  string | null {
  const formGroup = c.parent.controls;
  return Object.keys(formGroup).find(license_number => c === formGroup[license_number])  || null;
 }
```

but i don't know how to inject it to my formControl:

```
   constructor(private doctorsService: DoctorsService,
              private location: Location,
              private fb: FormBuilder) {
                this.rForm = new FormGroup({ 
                'name': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                'surname': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                'phone': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                'nationality': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                'email': new FormControl('', Validators.email),
                'license_number': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, ControlLicenseNumber])})
                 }
```

Hope you'll help me guys. Greetings

Comment: Where do would you like to place this validator? I see no `license_number` form control in your form? Also, why are you setting objects to your form controls? :)

Comment: Ok, I've eddited my code :)

Comment: I'm just learning and these objects are from some tutorial... so if it is wrong practice I deleted it as you told.

Comment: Looks better now :) Yes, form control should take only primitive value.(nested) formgroups are used for objects.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. What I should do next to validate license_number? I went throught the whole internet :/

Comment: Against what are you trying to validate the license number, now you have some attempt trying to find it from the object properties in the form, which I don't really understand?

Comment: I don't know if my logic is right(perhaps not) but I understand that function like this, that it returns every value for key "license_number" in object Doctor and it checks if this value is === input value.

Comment: You only have one license number field in your form/object as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, this validator has to get all license_numbers from database and compare it with input.

Comment: Aaah, okay. Well I don't see you even fetching any data. Now you are only trying to compare the license number to the other fields in your form.

Comment: So this "Object" from function is my object from form?

Comment: yes `c.parent.controls` refers to your formgroup, and you are iterating the object properties of that formgroup and comparing each propery to the license number.

Comment: So do you think I should getAllDoctors() from DB in validator?

Comment: No probably you don't need to do that, but you need to compare the license to THAT data. Also you need to bind `this` to your custom validator to preserve the context of `this`. After that I guess that you want something like... `this.allLicences.find(x => x.the_licensenumber_property === c.value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
constructor(private doctorsService: DoctorsService,
          private location: Location,
          private fb: FormBuilder) {
            this.rForm = this.fb.group({({ 
              name           : ['', [Validators.required]],
              surname        : ['', [Validators.required]],
              phone          : ['', [Validators.required],
              nationality    : ['',[Validators.required]],
              email          : ['', Validators.email],
              license_number : ['', [Validators.required]
              },
             {
                validator: this.ControlLicenseNumber
           });
}

ControlLicenseNumber(c: AbstractControl){
  const value = c.get('license_number').value;
  return Object.keys(value).find(license_number => c === 
  value)  || null;
}
```